# Is there an AmpScript plug-in for Visual Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking for a plug-in for AmpScript to use with Visual Studio so that Visual Studio would detect AmpScript keywords, maybe offer intellisense, etc.  Anything out there?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a good tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are AMPScript syntax highlighters [referenced on the wiki](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#section_31).

I currently use a customized version for Sublime Text 3, which was generously provided by [SeanJA on Github](https://github.com/SeanJA/ampscript-st2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one for Visual Studio but yesterday I discovered a text editor called Sublime which has an Ampscript plug-in (and HTML Ampscript for detecting a mixture of both)

https://www.sublimetext.com/

Instructions on how to get the package working are here:

https://github.com/SeanJA/ampscript-st2